# Migrating to rubinius

Tags: ruby, rubinius

I'm trying to migrate my project from `mri` to `rubinius` to get concurrency advantage.

I've started the server and open first page and then got error:

```
Puma caught this error: undefined method `=~' for Pathname (NameError)
kernel/common/module.rb:212:in `instance_method'
kernel/common/module.rb:354:in `undef_method'
kernel/bootstrap/array.rb:66:in `each'
kernel/common/module.rb:352:in `undef_method'
...
```

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.0', :engine => "rbx", engine_version: '2.2.1'

gem "rubysl" # Ruby Standard Library meta-gem for rubinius

# Server requirements

gem 'puma'

...
```

What might be a problem here?

UPDATE: [full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/sevenmaxis/7679503)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I examined your stack trace and looked at the Rubinius source code. The offending line is:

```
 class Pathname
   undef =~ # THIS IS IT
 end
```

`#=~` is an instance method on `Object` so normally `undef =~` should work on any class... *unless* it has been `undef`'d on `Object` or on `Pathname` already.

I'm wondering if this is happening because you have the `rubysl` gem in your Gemfile. I don't know Rubinius, but from what I can see, it doesn't seem to require you to specifically include this gem. Or maybe it did in past versions, but doesn't now. If the standard library is being loaded twice, that would explain why `undef =~` fails the second time.

If that doesn't help, I recommend you try temporarily removing as many gems as possible and see if the problem disappears. If so, add them back one by one until you find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Please look at the full stack trace in the question, it looks like some gem is not compatible with rubinius.

Comment: It doesn't work without rubysl, here's stracktrace of it https://gist.github.com/sevenmaxis/7689293

Comment: I launched my app by just commenting out that line.

Comment: Just as an experiment, see what happens if you do `class Foo (newline) undef to_s (newline) end` in Rubinius by itself.